# Call different functions based on buffer mode

Tags: key-bindings, hooks, major-mode

I annotate my reading with `org-remark` and `pdf-annot`. They work with EPUBs and PDFs respectively, and are not interchangeable, with [inconvenient consequences](https://github.com/nobiot/org-remark/issues/57#issue-1531569778).

What I would like to do is to bind a single key-binding to `org-remark-mark` and `pdf-annot-add-highlight-markup-annotation` based on the major mode of a buffer. If it is in `pdf-view-mode`, call `pdf-annot-add-highlight-markup-annotation`; if it is in `nov-mode`, call `org-remark-mark`.

At present, I have:

```lisp
(map! :leader
        (:prefix-map ("r" . "reading")
                     (:prefix ("n" . "org-noter")
                      :desc "PDF Add Highlight Annotation" "h" #'pdf-annot-add-highlight-markup-annotation
)))
```

and

```lisp
(map! :leader
        (:prefix-map ("r" . "reading")
        (:prefix ("r" . "org-remark")
        :desc "Highlight text at point" "h" #'org-remark-mark
)))
```

in my `config.el` on Doom Emacs.

I am thinking of working with hooks and conditionals, on a custom function, to be mapped onto <kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> in place of `org-remark-mark`, but fall short of implementing the actual code.

Comment: The normal approach is to bind your key sequence to `pdf-annot-add-highlight-markup-annotation` in `pdf-view-mode-map`, and separately bind it to `org-remark-mark` in `nov-mode-map` (n.b. I am making assumptions about the keymap names).

Comment: @phils There is, indeed, a `nov-mode-map` and a `pdf-view-mode-map`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly as @phils suggested in his comment above, but I've fixed the problem with this setting in `config.el`:

```lisp
  (map! :leader
        (:prefix-map ("r" . "reading")
        :desc "Make highlight annotation for EPUB or PDF" "h" #'my-reading-make-highlight-annotation))
```

```lisp
(defun my-reading-make-highlight-annotation ()

  "Highlight text and activate the annotation notes for input.
This single function can be called for both EPUBs and PDFs."

  (interactive)
  (cond ((eq major-mode 'nov-mode)
         (apply 'org-remark-mark (org-remark-region-or-word))
         (org-remark-view (- (point) 1))
         (switch-to-buffer "*marginal notes*")
         (evil-org-open-below 1))

        ((eq major-mode 'pdf-view-mode)
         (pdf-annot-add-highlight-markup-annotation pdf-view-active-region)
         (evil-insert 1)
         )))
```

Welcome other answers that propose to solve the problem in a more standard way.